# Multiply two dataframes condition on another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes: df1 and df2.

df1

```
Index date       | X1 | X2 
 0    01-01-2020 | H  | 10   
 1    01-02-2020 | H  | 30   
 2    01-03-2020 | Y  | 15    
 3    01-04-2020 | Y  | 20
```

df2

```
Index | X1 | X2 
 0    | H  | 5   
 1    | Y  | 10
```

I want to multiply df1 and df2 when the value on column X1 matches.

Desired result:

```
Index date       | X1 | X2 
 0    01-01-2020 | H  | 50   
 1    01-02-2020 | H  | 150   
 2    01-03-2020 | Y  | 150    
 3    01-04-2020 | Y  | 200
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for match by `X1` and then multiple by `X2`:

```
df1['X2'] *= df1['X1'].map(df2.set_index('X1')['X2'])
print (df1)
         date X1   X2
0  01-01-2020  H   50
1  01-02-2020  H  150
2  01-03-2020  Y  150
3  01-04-2020  Y  200
```

Or use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
df1['X2'] *= df2.merge(df1, on='X1', how='left')['X2_x']
print (df1)
         date X1   X2
0  01-01-2020  H   50
1  01-02-2020  H  150
2  01-03-2020  Y  150
3  01-04-2020  Y  200
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the index on both dataframes and assign the array to `df` :

```
df["X2"] = df.set_index("X1").X2.mul(df1.set_index("X1").X2).array

df

        date    X1  X2
0   01-01-2020  H   50
1   01-02-2020  H   150
2   01-03-2020  Y   150
3   01-04-2020  Y   200
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `df.merge` and `prod(axis=1)`

```
df1['X2']=df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='X1').filter(like='_').prod(axis=1)



    date      X1   X2
0  01-01-2020  H   50
1  01-02-2020  H  150
2  01-03-2020  Y  150
3  01-04-2020  Y  200
```